# Why is the pandas.Series.apply function with np.sum not applied to the entire Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, series

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
     a     b
0  aaa  22.0
1   bb  33.0
2    4  44.0
3    6  11.0
```

I want to sum the column `b`. I know that I can do np.sum(df['b']). But I want to understand syntax-wise why I can not use the following two to get the sum:

```
>>> df['b'].apply(np.sum, axis=0)
0    22.0
1    33.0
2    44.0
3    11.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
>>> df['b'].apply(np.sum)
0    22.0
1    33.0
2    44.0
3    11.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

**Why is the `apply` function with `np.sum` not applied to the whole series?**
In https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html it says

> Invoke function on values of Series.
>
> Can be ufunc (a NumPy function that applies to the entire Series) or a
> Python function that only works on single values.

The `np.sum` is for sure a "NumPy function". I think I may have misunderstanding with "Can be ufunc (a NumPy function that applies to the entire Series)" - **does this mean if it's a NumPy function then the function is applied to the entire Series at each cell value without aggregation**?

Comment: Series.apply applies the given function to each element in the series. To convince yourself, try the following `df['b'].apply(lambda x: x+1)`  which will add 1 to each element. You are essentially doing `df['b'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))` .

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `np.sum` is **not** a [Universal functions (ufunc)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html)

```
> isinstance(np.sum, np.ufunc)
False
```

`Series.apply` handles `ufunc` with `SeriesApply.apply_standard` internally

```py
class SeriesApply(NDFrameApply):
    obj: Series
    axis = 0

    def apply_standard(self) -> DataFrame | Series:
        # caller is responsible for ensuring that f is Callable
        f = cast(Callable, self.f)
        obj = self.obj

        with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
            if isinstance(f, np.ufunc):  # <------
                return f(obj)
```

If `f` is a numpy ufunc, it just pass the `obj` which is the Series itself to `f`.

So what you are using is just a function that only works on single values.

If you want to `sum` on the Series, you can use `Series.sum()` or `np.sum(Series)`.

```py
> df['b'].sum()
110.0

> np.sum(df['b'])
110.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `np.sum` to each element of the series `df['b']`. That's why you're not getting a scalar.

The method `apply()` takes a function as a parameter and applies it to the DataFrame column by column (where their values are the inputs). If the function used is aggregating (e.g `np.sum`, like yours), that is, it takes an input list and returns a single value. So, as a result, you will get a **Series**, with each element corresponding to a column.

With that being said, the equivalent of `np.sum(df['b'])` will be `df.apply(np.sum)['b']` which gives `110.0` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

From documentation, `np.sum Sum of array elements over a given axis`.

on the other hand `pd.apply passes a function and applies it on every single value of the Pandas series`

Thus, when combined like you have, summation will happen on the axis but on a single value.

So, you are better of just using `np.sum(df['b'])`, which by default will sum on the `axis=0` because thats what a pd series is.